# lazy loading is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

i want to display number of images in one page. For the best viewing i integrate lazy loading.

My javascript code is

```
<script src="{$this->scriptFolder}jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
<script src="{$this->scriptFolder}lazy_loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".lazy").lazyload({ 
            effect : "fadeIn"
         });
         $(window).scrollTop(1); 
     });
</script>
```

My html code is like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="span2" id="hider"> 
        <a href="/Magazine/index/get/52/" class="thumbnail magazine_cover">
            <img width="180" height="230" class="lazy" alt="cover" src="/public/demo.jpg" data-original="http://magsonwink.com/ECMedia/MagazineFiles/MAGAZINE-141/ISSUE-10085/CoverPage/Thumbnail/Outlook.jpg">
        </a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

but when i load this page the images are loading from different sections. I want to load images one by on

My staging site : http://staging.delhipress.thewinkstore.com/

if any one know about this please help me

Comment: This is most likely impossible to achieve with the current lazyload plugin since there's no way to queue how the images appear. They will show as soon as each image have finished loading.

Comment: if any alternative present for that

Comment: Not that I know of. Ask [Google](http://www.google.com) :)